# Angular 4 page is refreshing on mobile and in Safari

Tags: angular, safari, youtube-data-api

I'm having a tough time diagnosing this bug so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

In an Angular 4 app, I'm making an http.get call to the YouTube Data API--it all works fine in Chrome. However, in Safari, a refresh is happening. The URL briefly gets a "?" appended (e.g., http://localhost:4444/youtubetest becomes http://localhost:4444/youtubetest?). Execution stops at the http.get call and the page/app refreshes. Montioring with Charles Proxy shows that the response (200) is: Client closed connection before receiving entire response

No error appears and the page refresh happens quickly I can repro the issue in Safari.

Before the call that fails, I'm making a call to the YouTube search API that works fine: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search

What would cause this sort of behavior? It's not the http call that's really the issue because I can run it on its own (curl) and it works. There seems to be something going on with all the other pieces, but rather than post all the code, I'm wondering what to try next to diagnose the issue.

Here's the code that executes the HTTP call:

```
url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos',
      idKey: 'videoId',
      method: 'GET',
      ...

        return this.http.get(this.url, options)
          .map(response => response.json())
          .catch(this.handleError)
          .do(res => {
            // This does not run...
            console.log('returned video details');
          });
```

Answer (score 4):

As expected, it wasn't the http call, it was the Angular Material dialog hosting the button that made the call. Unless you add `type="button"`, Angular will assume you're trying to submit a form and that causes the page refresh.

See: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2599